# Xamarin.Forms Android App Crashes immediately after Launch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Im facing a weird issue. My app crashes immediately after launching with a Null Reference exception without reaching the first View.

So there is no issue with my code, thats why its so hard to find the issue.

```
08-06 20:41:01.951 D/Mono    ( 1695): [0x9c83f930] worker starting
08-06 20:41:01.953 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Core[0xabb78aa0] -> System.Dynamic.Runtime[0xabb79700]: 2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
08-06 20:41:01.970 D/Mono    ( 1695): [0x9c67f930] worker starting
08-06 20:41:01.972 D/Mono    ( 1695): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xae7d4460] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x9cd5d200]: 1
08-06 20:41:01.972 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xae7d4460] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
08-06 20:41:01.974 D/Mono    ( 1695): AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LindeXF.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
08-06 20:41:01.975 D/Mono    ( 1695): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LindeXF.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
08-06 20:41:01.975 D/Mono    ( 1695): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
08-06 20:41:01.975 D/Mono    ( 1695): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
08-06 20:41:01.975 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xabb789e0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xae7d4460]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
08-06 20:41:01.976 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xae7d4460] -> System.Xml[0xae7d3980]: 3
08-06 20:41:01.976 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xae7d4460] -> mscorlib[0xabb77ea0]: 49
08-06 20:41:01.980 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:01.980 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:01.980 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:01.980 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:01.987 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.Threading.Tasks[0xabb791c0]: 3
08-06 20:41:01.994 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40]: 2
08-06 20:41:01.994 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Collections[0xabb79340]: 4
08-06 20:41:01.994 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Xml.ReaderWriter[0xabb79580]: 3
08-06 20:41:01.995 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Reflection[0xabb79520]: 4
08-06 20:41:01.996 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.IO[0xabb79100]: 3
08-06 20:41:01.996 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Text.RegularExpressions[0xabb794c0]: 2
08-06 20:41:01.996 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Text.RegularExpressions[0xabb794c0] -> System[0xae7d23c0]: 8
08-06 20:41:02.006 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xae7d4460] -> System.ServiceModel.Internals[0xabb78f80]: 2
08-06 20:41:02.017 D/Mono    ( 1695): [0x9c83f930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
08-06 20:41:02.044 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0xae7d3980] -> System[0xae7d23c0]: 9
08-06 20:41:02.072 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Linq[0xabb797c0]: 4
08-06 20:41:02.080 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.ComponentModel[0xabb79d60]: 2
08-06 20:41:02.085 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.Linq.Expressions[0xabb79640]: 3
08-06 20:41:02.085 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.Reflection[0xabb79520]: 5
08-06 20:41:02.086 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0xae7d2ea0] -> System[0xae7d23c0]: 10
08-06 20:41:02.104 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Core[0xabb78aa0] -> System.ComponentModel[0xabb79d60]: 3
08-06 20:41:02.105 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0xabb79a00]: 4
08-06 20:41:02.110 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0xabb78d40] -> System.Globalization[0xabb79400]: 3
08-06 20:41:02.114 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Core[0xabb78aa0] -> System.Diagnostics.Debug[0xabb79880]: 3
08-06 20:41:02.136 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0xabb79340] -> System.Core[0xae7d2ea0]: 6
08-06 20:41:02.155 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.ObjectModel[0xabb79940]: 3
08-06 20:41:02.155 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.Collections[0xabb79340]: 5
08-06 20:41:02.156 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.Xml.XmlSerializer[0xae7d2480]: 2
08-06 20:41:02.156 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Xml.XmlSerializer[0xae7d2480] -> System.Xml[0xae7d3980]: 4
08-06 20:41:02.157 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF.Droid[0xabb77fc0] -> System[0xae7d23c0]: 11
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): Image addref System.Net.Http[0xae8a1dc0] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0x9c38be00]: 1
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly System.Net.Http[0xae8a1dc0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): AOT module 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LindeXF.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LindeXF.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref LindeXF[0xabb78a40] -> System.Net.Http[0xae8a1dc0]: 2
08-06 20:41:02.158 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xae8a1dc0] -> mscorlib[0xabb77ea0]: 50
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll
08-06 20:41:02.164 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xae8a1dc0] -> System[0xae7d23c0]: 12
Xamarin.Android returned no custom HttpClientHandler. Defaulting to System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
08-06 20:41:02.170 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
08-06 20:41:02.170 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
08-06 20:41:02.170 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
08-06 20:41:02.170 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
08-06 20:41:02.170 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing '__android_log_print'.
08-06 20:41:02.170 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as '__android_log_print'.
08-06 20:41:02.170 I/mono-stdout( 1695): Xamarin.Android returned no custom HttpClientHandler. Defaulting to System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
Thread started:  #5
08-06 20:41:02.198 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xae8a1dc0] -> System.Core[0xae7d2ea0]: 7
08-06 20:41:02.202 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xae7d2540] -> System[0xae7d23c0]: 13
08-06 20:41:02.224 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.224 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
08-06 20:41:02.224 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
08-06 20:41:02.224 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_int_method'.
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.226 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.269 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xabb789e0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4[0xabb787a0]: 2
08-06 20:41:02.290 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform[0xabb78c20] -> Xamarin.Forms.Core[0xabb78aa0]: 6
08-06 20:41:02.331 W/art     ( 1695): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.Platform_DefaultRenderer
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
08-06 20:41:02.349 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.349 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.349 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.349 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.353 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.353 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'.
08-06 20:41:02.353 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'.
08-06 20:41:02.353 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'.
08-06 20:41:02.354 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.354 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'.
08-06 20:41:02.354 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'.
08-06 20:41:02.354 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'.
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'.
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'.
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'.
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_is_assignable_from'.
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_is_assignable_from'.
08-06 20:41:02.357 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_is_assignable_from'.
08-06 20:41:02.358 D/Mono    ( 1695): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xae7d2540] -> System.Xml[0xae7d3980]: 5
08-06 20:41:02.360 W/art     ( 1695): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.LabelRenderer
08-06 20:41:02.364 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.364 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
08-06 20:41:02.364 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
08-06 20:41:02.364 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_local_ref'.
08-06 20:41:02.367 W/art     ( 1695): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ImageRenderer
08-06 20:41:02.416 D/Mono    ( 1695): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-06 20:41:02.416 D/Mono    ( 1695): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_int_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.416 D/Mono    ( 1695): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_int_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.416 D/Mono    ( 1695): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_int_method_a'.
08-06 20:41:02.438 D/OpenGLRenderer( 1695): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-06 20:41:02.441 D/GLHostConnection( 1695): Waiting for host to establish connection for PID 1695 (LindeXF.Droid)
08-06 20:41:02.442 D/GLHostConnection( 1695): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9bac2fa0, tid 1695
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I never faced this kind of issue maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: Have you tried debugging you MainActivity to see if you can catch the exception?

Comment: yeah i have the Exceptions doesnt get thrown at the MainActivity . I literally put everywhere a catch block with a message but the weird thing is that none of the exceptions gets thrown....

Comment: Please update your question with the code that is ran on starting your app

Comment: Open logcat, there should be some details about exception